# I want to create country specific url in wordpress. How to do that?

Tags: wordpress

I have searched everywhere but did not find anything. I do not want to create multisite.

I have tried using .htaccess file some kind of copy paste the code.

I want to make the links as given below:
i.e abc.com/in/whatever, abc.com/au/whatever

Comment: You could easily do this using a plugin I'm sure.. You need to search a bit harder, cause I don't believe you couldn't find 'anything'. Are you going to be showing completely different content based on country?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for multilingual plugins. [WPML](http://wpml.org) allows to set different url structure per language (you can have different top level domain for every language or as you show in example, you can specify language as directory)